# wordpress get all images by alt

Tags: image, wordpress, loops

I have many posts with many images therein. I have labelled a colour for each image in the alt field. So every image has a colour.

Now I need to find AND display all images based on that colour. And Id like to still be able to link to it's parent post. So im search all wordpress images based on the alt tag's contents.

This may take some nested loops, im not sure. I doubt there is an elegant way to do this.

Can anyone help me, should look something like this:

```
<a href="link to post"><img src="img source" alt="blue" /></a>
<a href="link to post"><img src="img source" alt="blue" /></a>
<a href="link to post"><img src="img source" alt="blue" /></a>
<a href="link to post"><img src="img source" alt="blue" /></a>
<a href="link to post"><img src="img source" alt="blue" /></a>
<a href="link to post"><img src="img source" alt="blue" /></a>
```

I have no other php markup, i don't know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `jQuery` solution

```
var imgs = $('img[alt|="blue"]');
alert(imgs.length);
```

For more on this selector go [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/).

Try this if you want to use pure JavaScript solution

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imgsBlue = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  if (imgs[i].alt == 'blue')
      imgsBlue.push(imgs[i]);
}
alert(imgsBlue.toString());
```

Comment: hmmm that would mean displaying all the image s first then hiding most of them wouldn't it ?

Comment: i really need a wordpress loop kind of solution